# Android Stomp reconnect to ActiveMQ

Tags: android, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using some Stomp library for android. I already success to create connection and consume message from ActiveMQ. But now I have a problem.

Every time the client(android) lost connection(like no internet), it seems that the connection to activeMQ not properly shutdown, so when I try to reconnect, it always make a new consumer for the destination queue. What I want is the android will reconnect using the same session as before so it will not create a new consumer for the queue. Can someone help me to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ identifies its durable STOMP subscriber with a `client-id` and `subscriptionName`. `Client-id` should be specified in the `CONNECT` message and `subscriptionName` should be specified in the `SUBSCRIBE` message. So, if you make sure that your subscriber uses the same client-id, subscriptionName combination every time it reconnects the ActiveMQ server, it should be treated as single client.

Please see [ActiveMQ STOMP Docs](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) for more information, specifically **ActiveMQ extensions to Stomp** section.